# Trying to use array in array made in jquery in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, arrays, highcharts

Here I am trying to create arrays in an array to use in Highcharts series data. However, the output is always a 1D array/ list.

The desired output: [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

```
var highchart_array = new Array();
var array;
   for (var i=0; i < data.fdata.length; i++){
   array=new Array();
   array.push(parseFloat(data.fdata[i][0]));
   array.push(parseFloat(data.fdata[i][1]));
   highchart_array.push(array);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Height (cm)'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (kg)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [highchart_array]

    }]
});

});
```

When the array is parsed into the Highcharts series data, it doesn't register.

Highchart code taken from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/scatter), I've just replaced the male and female data used in the example with the jquery array.

Any ideas? Or is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery creating two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933096/jquery-creating-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: Code shown [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/dx90jhga/)

Comment: @charlietfl that's true, but when I try to put that array into Highcharts series data it doesn't seem to work? I'll add the highcharts code to my question

Comment: Try just `data: highchart_array` without the outer `[]`

Comment: it works!!! thanks you so much, really appreciate it, its been bugging me for hours